# Quadratic equation $4x^2+4x=7$ using quadratic formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Solve using quadratic formula. $4x^2+4x=7$

So $4x^2+4x-7=0$

$A=4$ $b=4$ $c=-7$

$$x=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{(4)^2-4(4)(-7)}}{2(4)}=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{16+112}}{8}=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{128}}{8}$$

What's next?

Comment: you nay write $\displaystyle \sqrt{128}=\sqrt{2}\cdot{\sqrt{64}}=8\sqrt{2}$ and then you have $\displaystyle x=\frac{-4+8\sqrt{2}}{8}=\frac{-1+2\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and these are your solutions.

Comment: If you are going to keep using this site you need to learn how to format your questions (and when you post one answers) so math looks like math.  There is a tutorial here [MathJax basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/86986).

Answer (score 2):

Next is simplifying:

$$x=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{4^2-4\cdot4\cdot-7}}{2\cdot4}=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{16+112}}{8}=-\frac12\pm\frac18\cdot8\sqrt{2}=-\frac12\pm\sqrt2$$

Comment: Where did you get the 1/2 and 1/4?

Comment: $\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{128}}{8}=\frac{-4}{8}\pm\frac18\sqrt{128}=\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

I can't see what you have written but it should look like:

$$\begin{align}
4x^2+4x-7&=0
\\ \Rightarrow x_{\pm}&=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{(4)^2-4(4)(-7)}}{2(4)}
\\ &=\frac{-4\pm{\sqrt{16+112}}}{8}
\\&=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{128}}{8}
\\ &=\frac{-4+\sqrt{128}}{8}\,\,\,\text{ or }\frac{-4-\sqrt{128}}{8}
\\ &=\frac{-4+\sqrt{8^2\cdot 2}}{8}\,\,\,\text{ or }\frac{-4-\sqrt{8^2\cdot 2}}{8}
\\ &=\frac{-4+\sqrt{8^2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}{8}\,\,\,\text{ or }\frac{-4-\sqrt{8^2}\cdot \sqrt{2}}{8}
\\ &=\frac{-4+8\cdot \sqrt{2}}{8}\,\,\,\text{ or }\frac{-4-8\cdot \sqrt{2}}{8}
\\ &=-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}\,\,\,\text{ or }-\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{2}.
\end{align}$$

The approximate values of these may be found using a calculator.